# Prove or disprove that $|a|=|b|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In group theory:

> If $|a^2|=|b^2|$ then prove or disprove that $|a|=|b|$. (where $|a|$ denotes the order of the element $a$)

Let $|a|=n, |b|=m$

$|a^2|=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,2)}=\frac{m}{\gcd(m,2)}=|b^2|$

Then it is possible that, $n$ is odd and $m=2n$, so it does not follow that $|a|=|b|$, am I correct ?

Comment: What's wrong with $|a^2| = |b^2| \implies a^2 = b^2 \implies a = \pm b \implies |a| = |b|$?

Comment: @barak manos I think, the task is to prove that it is not necessarily true, but there are cases, where it holds.

Comment: With the group-theory tag, you have me wondering if possibly $|a|$ means order of the group element $a$?

Comment: @paw88789 Of course the order of an element

Comment: You are correct. For a counter-example you can take $3$-cycle in some symmetric group and the product of a transposition and a $3$-cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you look at an example of a nonidentity element $a$ in some group that squares to the identity?  Then look at $a$ and $e$.